# Google App Engine converting string to propery(of Entity)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class Personel(db.Model):
  ismarried=db.StringProperty()


class AddPersonal(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    per=Personal()
    #i want use a function at below, instead of per.ismarried
    per.whatisthisfunction("ismarried")="yes"
    per.put
```

I want convert string to entity's propery. Can it possible as above.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(per, "ismarried", "yes")
```